# Why bother returning a value in http.createServer()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm doing the learnyounode workshop and I'm curious about this snippet from one of the offical solutions.

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.method != 'POST')
    return res.end('send me a POST\n')
})
```

I'm just curious why they bother returning a value at all. You could just call res.end() and it will work as expected (as I expect anyway). It looks like end() is just returning a boolean value but I don't understand why you would need or want to return anything.

Comment: Well if you have code after res.end and you're not returning (exiting), then the rest of the code will run too.

Comment: @dave Chen good point. I guess im just curious if the return value is used internally by nodejs. Basically, am I doing it wrong if I don't return true/false when im done handling the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of this function doesn't actually go anywhere although in theory it could:

```
http.createServer = function (cb) {
    if (cb()) { /* do something */ }
};
```

As far as I know, `.createServer` doesn't actually do this internally for any reason. The reason why you would want to use `return` in this case would be to short circuit the function execution, e.g.

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.method != 'POST')
    return res.end('send me a POST\n')

  res.end('POST sent\n');
})
```

Of course an `if`/`else` could prevent continuing execution of the function anyway, but you can use `return` in callback functions for either of these reasons.

Answer (score 3):

The function you pass to http.createServer is added to an EventEmitter instance [as an listener for request event](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js#L227).

The return value returned by listeners passed to EventEmitter are ignored, [proof](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L82).

So the only benefit of using `return` statement in this case is for returning earlier and to ignore the rest of the function in case it exists, as was said by [Explosion Pills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454533/explosion-pills).